# Create new CRM integration for Facebook Ads

Tags: facebook, integration, webhooks, crm, lead

We have a CRM for our applications, which provides services to other institutions which they have their own customers and users. We went through webhook integration for our own institution but the process is a little bit tricky. My question is how can we register our crm in Facebook registered crm list (for lead generation process) so with just couple of clicks we can integrate with each institution. The Facebook does not provide any information regarding this process or atleast I could not find one, and they won't answer support messages:) if any one knows how to do this please let us know.

Comment: You can try https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/298606028106744 to apply.

Comment: thank you for your answer :) i will check and in case of success i will vote up your comment.

Comment: any update to this? looking for same thing where to get information for this?